# issues with clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I cannot seem to get clearInterval to work in the manner that I believe it should. I have been going through so many other examples and questions. In each case I seem to be doing what everyone else is doing, excepting the use of onkeypress. I have also tried various other keypress options with no luck. And I have also flipped around the code a bunch of different times to no avail.

Below is the basic pieces of code I have been working with, much simplified from the larger project. As you might be able to discern, I want it to keep printing "poop " until a keypress stops it. If I hit a button before it prints "poop" the first time, it will stop and print "stopped pooping." If I wait until after it has printed "poop" once, I cannot get it to stop with a keypress.

Please excuse the scatological nature of it.

```
function pooping() {
    document.write("poop ");
}

var pooper = setInterval(pooping, 1000);

document.onkeypress = function() {
    clearInterval(pooper);
    pooper = 0;
    document.write("stopped pooping");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `document.write()` will do that. That's why we don't use it anymore. At all.

Comment: Could be something else is overwriting `document.onkeypress`. You should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead (and what @Madara said)

Comment: replace `document.write` with `console.log` http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp - "If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML."

Comment: Thanks folks! Lesson learned. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same code, without the `document.write()` works fine:

```js
'use strict';

let target = document.getElementById('target');
function pooping() {
    // Normally would use console.log() here, but wanted the result visible
    // in the snippet.
    target.textContent += "poop ";
}

var pooper = setInterval(pooping, 1000);

document.onkeypress = function() {
    clearInterval(pooper);
    pooper = 0;
    target.textContent += "stopped pooping";
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```